# arithmectic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

what is the 100th trerm of the arithmectic sequence? 3,8,13,18
 can you help me find it, i know there a formula but i dont rember what it is !!!!!!

ive know you have to pluge it in to some kind of formula but i dont know which one it was. so if any one knows it let me knnow A.S.A.P!!

I have done a few already but they were easy about i dont knoe how to fine the 100th term in the problem!

Comment: By the way, I did provide an answer, but next time, please leave off the urgency, etc. It is bad form.

Answer (score 2):

The given series is: $3,8,13,18......$

The given series is an AP with common difference $d=5$

And for an AP the equation for general term is

$$T_n=a+(n-1)d\;$$
where 'a' represents the first term and 'd' represents the common difference.

On substituting the values of 'a' and 'd' we get the 100th term as :

$T_{100}=3+(100-1)5=498$. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

$$a_n = 5 (n-1)+3$$

Comment: okay thanks! im working on e2020 and its killig me

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I find when teaching people this it is better not to just memorize what the $n$-th term formula is but to figure out why it is what it is...or else one day you will forget it again! (Trust me, I find myself reminding students of this all the time).

So the first term is $a$, to get the second we add our common difference $d$ to get $a+d$. To get the third term we add another $d$ to get $a+2d$...

You can see that by the time we get to the $n$-th term we have added $n-1$ many $d$'s, i.e. the $n$-th term should be $a + (n-1)d$.